# EMACS regex,How to work only in the designated few lines

Tags: regex, emacs

For example, I just want it to work in the 1-10 lines, how to do it. A rookie, thanks for help.

Comment: Why this question is closed?  I think that it is a very helpful question. If [Bill the Lizard] has ever worked with emacs, this question make sense very easily. The question makes sense, if combined with the title.

Answer (score 2):

You can use narrow-mode, and it will display only the first 10 lines, hiding the rest.

Comment: This is a good idea.Useful,thanks.